# Using same variable multiple times in a loop

Tags: python

I have come across an example where a variable i is used on the outer for loop and also in the inner for loop. If i change the variable i to j in the inner for loop the result is different. Can you explain what's going on?

How is

```
print("Fifth Number Pattern")
lastNumber = 9
for i in range(1, lastNumber):
    for i in range(0, i, 1):
        print(format(2**i, "4d"), end=' ')
    for i in range(-1+i, -1, -1):
        print(format(2**i, "4d"), end=' ')
    print(" ")
```

different from

```
print("Fifth Number Pattern")
lastNumber = 9
for i in range(1, lastNumber):
  for j in range(0, i, 1):
    print(format(2**j, "4d"), end=' ')
  for j in range(-1+i, -1, -1):
    print(format(2**j, "4d"), end=' ')
  print("")`
```

Comment: Have you tried a debugger or working through the code using pencil and paper?

Comment: You need to reset value of i at the start of the loop, `i=0`. Further you are using i in everyloop, so i is incremented in itself also as well as by `-1+i`. You can see where you have problem.

Comment: @quamrana I compiled both the codes and the results are different. I am trying to find out whats going on using pencil and paper.

Comment: @harshitverma I am just trying to understand why the output is different in the cases above.

Comment: use `print(i)` in different places to see differences.

Comment: I would say that the first piece of code is wrong because i is changed by the second for loop and by the time the third for loop starts i is not as the first loop left it. The second piece of code uses j as the loop variable, leaving i as the same value throughout both the second and third loops.

Comment: You have updated the value of i in the first inner loop, so when second loop comes into the action, the value of i is changed and the second loop will take that value for `i+1` so increment affects `i+1` as well, whereas in case of j, there is no affect to `i+1`

Answer (score 0):

In your code `i` and `j` are the indexes of your for loop. By default they are assumed to start at zero.

In your first example of code. `i` starts at 0 so all of your other nested for-loops `i` is zero. When the first iteration of your outer loop is over `i` is incremented to 1. Meaning, all of your other `i`'s in your nested-loops have incremented to 1 as well and `range(0,i,1)` has increased the amount of times each of your nested loops will iterate.

In your second case, you have separated your index variables `i` and `j` meaning that when your outer loop, that is based on the value of `i`, increments up the values of `j` are unchanged for every iteration of `i`.

Hence, the difference in output your are experiencing.